# How to implement dynamic hashing in a hash table in Python?

Tags: python, hashtable

I'm new to Python and currently I have a hash table class that resolves collisions through linear probing. However, if the load factor is above 2/3, I want to double the size of the array. However, I keep getting the error

```
if self.array[i]!=None:
IndexError: invalid index
```

Is it because every time I change my table size the size doesn't update in my `getLoadandAverageProbeLength`?

My set item function:

```
 def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    position = self.hash_value(key)
    sameKeyCollision=False
    load,averageProbeLength= self.getLoadAndAverageProbeLength(self.totalProbeLength)
    loadFactor=load
    if loadFactor<(2/3):
        if self.array[position] is None:#found empty slot, collision resolve
            self.array[position] = (key, value)
            self.count += 1
            sameKeyCollision=False


            return
        elif self.array[position][0] == key:#found key
            self.array[position] = (key, value)#update value, no collision
            return
        elif self.array[position][0] !=key and sameKeyCollision==False:#not found try next,first time collision
            position = (position+1) % self.table_size
            self.totalProbeLength+=1
            self.collision+=1
            sameKeyCollision=True
        elif self.array[position][0] !=key and sameKeyCollision==True:#probing
            position = (position+1) % self.table_size
            self.totalProbeLength+=1
```

My `getLoadAndAverageProbeLength`

```
def getLoadAndAverageProbeLength(self,probeLength):
    count=0
    averageProbeLength=0
    for i in range(self.table_size):
        if self.array[i]!=None:
            count+=1

    load= count/self.table_size

    if count!=0:
        averageProbeLength=probeLength/count
    return load,averageProbeLength
```

This is my class constructor for my hash table:

```
def __init__(self, size=2):
    self.count = 0
    self.table_size = size
    self.array = build_array(self.table_size)
    self.collision=0
    self.totalProbeLength=0
```

This is my traceback:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment3Task3(b).py", line 18, in <module>
main()
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment3Task3(b).py", line 15, in main
readFile(filename)
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment3Task3(b).py", line 10, in readFile
hashTable[line]=line
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment3Task4.py", line 55, in __setitem__
self.__setitem__(key,value)
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment3Task4.py", line 29, in __setitem__
load,averageProbeLength= self.getLoadAndAverageProbeLength(self.totalProbeLength)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment3Task4.py", line 83, in getLoadAndAverageProbeLength
if self.array[i]!=None:
```

IndexError: invalid index

Comment: why are you writing your own hash table implementation instead of using the builtin ``dict`` ?

Comment: Can you show `self.array`'s definition, and if it is changed anywhere else?

Comment: I added it already

Comment: @IrmendeJong, I think he's learning how a dictionary works internally.

Comment: @SookLim, may we get the full traceback?

Comment: I updated it already

Comment: may I see the definition of `build_array()`?